# How to routes Controller sub folder using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, routes

I have created controller file in sub folder of controller.

i have two type of sub folder for backend(admin) and frontend(user).

Structure of Controller

```
Controller
--backend
   ---admin.php
   ---dashboard.php
--frontend
   ---user.php
```

I want url for admin panel:

```
http://localhost/DemoSite/admin_panel/admin/dashboard
```

**admin_panel** want it in URL before every backend controller call

admin is Controller
dashboard is Function

For frontend :

```
http://localhost/DemoSite/user
```

I have done route like this :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'frontend/user';
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "backend/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = "user/$1";
```

Comment: in controller folder you made 2 folders?

Comment: Yes, i created two folder in Controller folder

Comment: should I post proper folder structure? you are going in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete the last line in routes and create multiple routes to user:

```
//user routes
$route['default_controller'] = 'frontend/user';
$route['user'] = "frontend/user";

//admin routes
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "backend/$1";
```